# REST API Design Scenario

Tags: rest, microservices

I would like to check if a parent order is eligible to be deleted without retrieving the order details. The parent order is eligible to be deleted if all the child orders have been deleted. I have an endpoint designed similar to what is listed below

```
/parent-order/{parent-order-id} [ Return ParentOrder object]
```

However I was to check if the parent-order is eligible to be deleted without retrieving the details of the parent-order. "isEligibleToBeDeleted" is not an attribute of the parent order. Which of the below is a better approach to do this or are there any other alternatives?

```
/parent-order/{parent-order-id}/is-eligible-to-be-deleted [ returns true of eligible to be deleted and false if not]
```

or

```
/parent-order/is-eligible-to-be-deleted/{parent-order-id} [ returns true of eligible to be deleted and false if not]
```

or

```
    /parent-order/{parent-order-id}?isEligibleToBeDeleted=True 
[ This is an enhancement on the existing endpoint which returns ParentOrder object if it is eligible to deleted and false otherwise ]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it largely depends on the general logic of URL structures in this API and also on what is supposed to be done about the result. If you could possibly specify these two points, the answers may be more instructive.

For now, I can only say the following:

- the first option looks more logical to me than the second, because its structure is more solid: What are we looking at? - `parent-order`. Which one? - the one with `{order-id}`. What do we need from it? - to find out if it `is-eligible-to-be-deleted`.
- the last option is very dubious. Before I read what it does, by just a brief look at it I got a wrong impression that it would return a list of parent-orders that are eligible to be deleted. Yes, there was that suspicious `{parent-order-id}` in between, but my eye caught the param after `/?`. So, the latter looks somewhat non-conventional and therefore error-prone.

It may also be important to take into consideration what other methods this `/parent-order/` endpoint is supposed to have (if any). For example, it there are some other actions to be performed with those parent-orders, it may a good option to pack them all under some general endpoint, like `/parent-orders/{order-id}/check`, that accepts some instructions as to what to return and acts accordingly. For instance, when it receives something like `{"check": "is_eligible_to_be_deleted"}`, it returns checks this. But it may also get something like `{"check": "is_eligible_to_be_processed"}` and other things, and respond accordingly.